# Loop and concatenate same Array

Tags: php, arrays

I try to concatenate a variable array inside an foreach

```
Foreach (item as $orderitem) {
//for each item I have to get the array below
$prodord[] .= array(
        'variant_id' => $variant_id,
        'quantity' => 2
);
$orderData = array('order' => array(
'line_items' => array(
//the following variable is when I need to put the array if is one item
//or two arrays if are two item        
$prodord
/*array(
        'variant_id' => $variant_id,
        'quantity' => 1
    )*/
)
));
```

I've tried to concatenate the arrays to have a variable with value like this

```
//First item 
array(
    'variant_id' => 123456,
    'quantity' => 1
),
//2d item
array(
    'variant_id' => 654321,
    'quantity' => 1
)
```

But my output look like

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(5) "Array"
[1]=>
string(5) "Array"
}
```

With one item it works perfect.

Comment: Just forget the dot `.` , that is for string concatenation: `$prodord[] = array(.........` The `[]` syntax creates a new array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember when you work with variables in php you dont need to use [this] for insert values into the variable, if the variable is declared as array you only need to push the next values, for example;

```
$prodord = array(); //Here we declared the Var as array
```

after this we can use this variable into 'for' or 'foreach' or wherever you want and concatenate like this example;

```
array_push($prodord, array('variant_id' => $variant_id,'quantity' => 1));
```

so in this line we push a new value to my Array $prodord and you can do this anytime you want, if you look i push an array into the array with the values and variables to get the info.